# Pythons hashlib producing different hash value than the original hash

Tags: python, hash, md5sum

I saved this piece of code as `hash.py` and when I produce the hash of this file it gives me  a hash totally differing from the inbuilt (using KUbuntu 13.04), Now why is that so ? Aren't they both supposed to produce the same result. I also have to mention that for calculating hash value of huge files (I tested on 4.5GB iso file) with the inbuilt md5sum it at least takes 7 seconds but this python file is almost instant

```
""" filename: hash.py """
import sys
import hashlib
file_name = sys.argv[0]
hash_obj = hashlib.md5(file_name)
print "MD5 - "+ hash_obj.hexdigest()
```

Output:

```
meow@VikkyHacks:~/Arena/py$ python hash.py 
MD5 - d18a4085140ad0c8ee7671d8ba2065fc
```

Output from the inbuilt default command:

```
meow@VikkyHacks:~/Arena/py$ md5sum hash.py 
5299f3588cb0de6cf27930181be73e80  hash.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are extracting the file path from `sys.argv[0]` and compute its md5 (that is, the md5 of the path as a string). To compute the md5 of the file contents, use:

```
import sys
import hashlib

file_path = sys.argv[0]
with open(file_path, 'rb') as file_handle:
    file_contents = file_handle.read()
    print('MD5 - ' + hashlib.md5(file_contents).hexdigest())
```

### EDIT

Using `hashlib.md5(open(file_name, 'rb').read())` is a bad practice because it does not close the file properly.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case you are hashing the file *name*, in the second you are hashing the file's *contents*.

Comment: sorry for not putting up the code the first time, I am trying to hash the same source file's content by passing `argv[0]` and passing the contents of hash.py to `md5sum`

Comment: @vikkihacks: To compute the md5sum of the *contents*, use `hashlib.md5(open(file_name, 'rb').read())`.